# CloudFoundry Java Client throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, oauth-2.0

I am getting a NullPointerException error while trying to set up CloudFoundry java client.

The flow goes like this: UI App is protected using CF OAuth which asks users to enter username and password. Once authenticated, the user authorizes the UI to use its resources in CF. This generates an access-token.

I am trying to set up Client using this Access-Token to do some work at CF using Java APIs. However, it throws a NullPointerException. The code snippet is as below. I'm getting the error at the penultimate line.

The `OAuth2AccessToken` class is not allowing me to set `refreshToken`.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

**Code I am using:**

```
org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken token = new    org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(tokenToUse);
CloudCredentials cloudCredentials = new CloudCredentials(token);
HttpProxyConfiguration proxyConfig = buildProxyConfiguration(targetUrl);
// Error occurs here
client = new CloudFoundryClient(cloudCredentials, targetUrl, orgToUse, spaceToUse, proxyConfig, selfSigned);
client.login();
```

Debugging (grep code) this further shows that the error is coming from the following snippet (line 3) in `ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider` class.

```
public OAuth2AccessToken refreshAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource,
                            OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken, AccessTokenRequest request) throws UserRedirectRequiredException,
                            OAuth2AccessDeniedException {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    form.add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    // Line 3
    form.add("refresh_token", refreshToken.getValue());
    return retrieveToken(request, resource, form, new HttpHeaders());
}
```

**Exception Stack**:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.refreshAccessToken(ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider.java:39)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.oauth2.OauthClient.refreshToken(OauthClient.java:126)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.oauth2.OauthClient.getToken(OauthClient.java:88)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.oauth2.OauthClient.getAuthorizationHeader(OauthClient.java:97)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl$CloudFoundryClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:385)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:76)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:538)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.LoggingRestTemplate.doExecute(LoggingRestTemplate.java:54)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:503)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:240)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.getAllResources(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:1213)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.getSpaces(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:647)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.validateSpaceAndOrg(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:202)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientImpl.(CloudControllerClientImpl.java:178)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.rest.CloudControllerClientFactory.newCloudController(CloudControllerClientFactory.java:78)
>       at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryClient.(CloudFoundryClient.java:164)

Comment: Gurus, any suggestions??